# How to remove a charlist from a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, list, replace

How can I remove a specific list of chars from a string?

For example I have the string `Multilanguage File07` and want to remove all vowels, spaces and numbers to get the string `MltlnggFl`.

Is there any shorter way than using a `foreach` loop?

```
string MyLongString = "Multilanguage File07";
string MyShortString = MyLongString;
char[] charlist = new char[17]
  { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
    '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', ' ' };
foreach (char letter in charlist)
{
    MyShortString = MyShortString.Replace(letter.ToString(), "");
}
```

Comment: "any shorter way" what exactly do you mean? less code?

Comment: I don't like
a) the way of writing so many apostrophes (') and
b) having to count the number of chars (in that case [17]) to define the charlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this code to replace a list of chars within a string:**

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string MyLongString = "Multilanguage File07";
string MyShortString = Regex.Replace(MyLongString, "[aeiou0-9 ]", "");
```

**Result:**
`Multilanguage File07` => `MltlnggFl`
`Text from which some chars should be removed 12345` => `Txtfrmwhchsmchrsshldbrmvd`

**Explanation of how it works:**
The Regex Expression I use here, is a list of independend chars defined by the brackets []
=> `[aeiou0-9 ]`
The Regex.Replace() iterates through the whole string and looks at each character, if it will match one of the characters within the Regular Expression.
Every matched letter will be replaced by an empty string ("").

Comment: I added an Explanation of how it works. Thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var charList = new HashSet<char>(“aeiou0123456789 “);

MyLongString = new string(MyLongString.Where(c => !charList.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: have an upvote for using a `HashSet` and for removing the double linq statement

Comment: I don't like it because it is still too much to write (too many apostrophes and commas). For each char you have to type at least 4 letters on the keyboard...

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `(?|([aeyuio0-9 ]+))`. Replace it with empty string and you will get your desird result.

I used branch reset `(?|...)` so all characters are captured into one group for easier manipulation.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/ZP5c7y/1)

Comment: Thank you for the link to regex101.com
This website is really good!
But I still don't understand what the term `(?|...)` is good for. If I don't use it I still get only 1 regex group.

Comment: @MichaelHutter You don't have to use it. But when you use `\1` in substitution and play with it, you'll understand how it works. But only for your task, it doesn't need to have branch reset `(?|...)`. If my answer helped you, you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void removeVowels()
{
       string str = "MultilanguAge File07";
       var chr = str.Where(c => !"aeiouAEIOU0-9 ".Contains(c)).ToList();
       Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", chr));
}
```

**1st line:** creating desire string variable.

**2nd line:** using linq ignore vowels words [captital case,lower case, 0-9 number & space] and convert into list.

**3rd line:** combine chr list into one line string with the help of string.join function.

**result: MltlnggFl7**

**Note:**  removeVowels function not only small case, 1-9 number and empty space but also remove capital case word from string.